# Windows Authentication in other applications (like Google-chrome)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, security, authentication

I have a question about windows authentication in other application like Google chrome.

I know about LDAP and I think my question should be something else.

Example: When I want to see my saved password in Google Chrome, it asked me my windows password.

1- How Google chrome is able to identify me? is it something available by windows, if yes that means I can use it even in any windows application.

(Considering this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-does-google-chrome-know-my-windows-password/ab41686a-e278-4ae1-83b1-186fdcdbf26d) Microsoft API should get the password and verify it but how can we use this API in our application?).

2- Is it secure from any kind of attack to password?

is there any one who can answer me in detail or give me the links?

Appreciate in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, this is `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`. On Mac this is `AuthorizationCopyRights`. See [src/chrome/browser/password_manager/‌password_manager_util_win.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/password_manager/password_manager_util_win.cc?rcl=69a11d9f02b4a040825fef0cc44ead230566789f&l=444)

This could conceivably be a vector for a program to phish the user's password if the user is unable to distinguish between a system credential prompt and an ordinary window. But the whole point of this is that your web browser is storing many website passwords, and rather leaving them exposed on disk they are protected at the OS level with the user's login credentials.

One way to see the effect of this is with the Mac [build of Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) (possibly Windows as well, but I have not tested), since the app is not codesigned. When you download a new version, you get a system prompt to confirm access to "Chromium Safe Storage". So not only is Chrome using its discretion to divulge stored passwords and reauthenticate the user, the operating system also makes a policy decision based on the app's signature.

Comment: Thanks. I search a lot to find it. What did you search? At my work if I want to connect to Internet it asks me my windows password in webform application. It should be the same history with Chrome, isn't it?

Comment: Start at https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=onShowPasswordButtonTap and go one hop at a time.